# How can I make my BATCH file affect subfolders?

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I have a BATCH file which deletes every other JPG file. I am looking to make it so that when it is run, it affect all subfolders as well.

I am not a coder by all means, so apologies if this is a rookie question!

Below is my current code:

```
@echooff

setlocal
for /r %%D in (.) do (
  set "del="
  for /f %%F in ('dir /b "%%D\*.jpg"') do if defined del (
    del "%%D\%%F"
    set "del="
  ) else set "del=1"
)

PAUSE
```

Comment: Can you please explain what specifically you want to happen by the term "deletes every other JPG file"? Your code does not place any files into a specific order, whilst it may appear that they are, they're not, you're already using a command which allows some sorting, so you'd be advised to utilise it. If the files order doesn't matter, are you simply deleting half of the `.jpg` files in each subdirectory of a tree?

Comment: Hi Compo! So I have folders filled with images named 00001.jpg, 00002.jpg etc... What I want to happen is that running this program deletes every other image in their numerical order. For example, if I have files named 01, 02, 03, 04... 10 then I want to delete 02, 04, 06, 08, & 10. Hope this helps!

Comment: No it doesn't, it only really leads to more questions. Are you wanting to keep only odd numbered images, or does the numbers not really matter? What happens if your directory contains `01`, `02`, `05`, `06` and `08`, do you want to delete `02` and `06`?. So is it a perfect sequence? and can you guarantee that each file name is numeric only? and has exactly the same number of characters? _(As you should know, Windows does not do a numeric sort, its alphabetic, i.e. `1`, `10`, `11`, `2`, `22`, `3` etc.)_

Comment: Every image is consistently numbered in the same format (00001.jpg, 00002.jpg...) consistently going upwards into the 10 thousand range. There are no deviations on this name-scheme, although I may be manually cutting out segments, so for example I may have 10000 files labelled 00001.jpg - 11000.jpg, with files 08000.jpg to 08999.jpg being manually deleted prior.    Either deleting all of the odd or even integers could work, or alternatively deleting every other image in alphabetical order. Does this make more sense?

Comment: The code I have above does work, deleting every other jpg in alphabetical order. However, I want to apply this so it will run the same process in sub folders too

Answer (score 1):

The `/S` switch in the `dir` makes you go through subdirectories, as you can see here:

```
dir /?
...
  /S          Displays files in specified directory and all subdirectories.
...
```

So I'd advise you to replace:

```
dir /b "%%D\*.jpg"
```

by:

```
dir /S /b "%%D\*.jpg"
```

Good luck

Comment: Hi Dominique! I have just tried this and the following error message came up. Any chance you know what I might have done wrong?      'The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.'

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your clarifications, is this what you're trying to achieve:

```batch-file
@SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
@For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%G In ('Dir /B/S/A:D 2^>NUL') Do @(Set "_="
    For /F "EOL=?Delims=" %%H In ('Dir /B/A:-D/O:N "%%G\*.jpg" 2^>NUL')Do @(
        If Not Defined _ (Set "_=T")Else Del /A/F "%%G\%%H"&Set "_="))
```